# Best means of determining cause of GNOME sporadically going into standby

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, gnome, standby

This has been eating at me for a bit now.  I have a small netbook computer running Ubuntu 10.04.  It loves to sporadically go into standby, turning off the screen, spinning down the disk, pausing for about 10 seconds, and then after hitting the keyboard, waking up again to a password prompt.  As soon as I put the password in, everything resumes as normal from where it left off, which is why I am convinced it is going into standby.

I cannot seem to determine the cause of the Standby based on the symptoms however.  Coretemp and other temp utilities do not report high temps (usually under 30C), the GNOME power-preferences panel is not set to go into standby at all, and as far as I know, my memory is doing just fine and not being overly utilized.

I am stumped.  What is the best way to start diagnosing this problem in the logs and or settings.  I have never had this problem with other Ubuntu  10.04 installations, and I run a lab full of them, so I am thinking it is somehow laptop related.

My modules loaded at boot (/etc/modules):

```
lp
battery
ac
thermal
processor
acpi-cpufreq
cpufreq-userspace
coretemp
```

Cheers!

EDIT: Here is a kern.log extract from the time it enters standby to the time it wakes up.

```
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10200.164734] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10200.176850] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10200.176860] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.00 seconds) done.
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10200.179399] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.00 seconds) done.
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10200.179665] PM: Entering mem sleep
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10200.179688] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10200.180743] option: option_instat_callback: error -2
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10200.196424] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10200.358489] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10200.849071] PM: suspend of drv:sd dev:2:0:0:0 complete after 652.638 msecs
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10200.849113] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.319507] PM: suspend of drv:psmouse dev:serio1 complete after 439.360 msecs
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.424190] PM: suspend of drv:atkbd dev:serio0 complete after 104.642 msecs
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.429477] ACPI handle has no context!
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.429936] wl 0000:05:00.0: PCI INT A disabled
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.444880] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: PCI INT B disabled
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.460336] ata2: port disabled. ignoring.
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.460467] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.1: PCI INT B disabled
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.460496] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: PCI INT A disabled
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.460512] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: PCI INT D disabled
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.460527] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: PCI INT C disabled
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.460541] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: PCI INT B disabled
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.460555] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: PCI INT A disabled
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.564238] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A disabled
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.580196] PM: suspend of drv:HDA Intel dev:0000:00:1b.0 complete after 119.600 msecs
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.633427] i915 0000:00:02.0: PCI INT A disabled
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.648493] PM: suspend of devices complete after 1468.441 msecs
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.648500] PM: suspend devices took 1.472 seconds
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.664361] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 15.851 msecs
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.664401] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.764028] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.764067] CPU0 attaching NULL sched-domain.
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.764076] CPU1 attaching NULL sched-domain.
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.828033] CPU0 attaching NULL sched-domain.
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.829261] Breaking affinity for irq 9
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.829275] Breaking affinity for irq 12
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.829292] Breaking affinity for irq 16
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.829303] Breaking affinity for irq 18
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.932040] CPU 1 is now offline
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.932045] SMP alternatives: switching to UP code
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.938435] Extended CMOS year: 2000
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.938435] Back to C!
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.938435] CPU0: Thermal monitoring handled by SMI
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.938435] Extended CMOS year: 2000
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.938435] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.938435] SMP alternatives: switching to SMP code
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.943887] Booting processor 1 APIC 0x1 ip 0x6000
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.937386] Initializing CPU#1
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.937386] Atom PSE erratum detected, BIOS microcode update recommended
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.937386] CPU: L1 I cache: 32K, L1 D cache: 24K
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.937386] CPU: L2 cache: 512K
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.937386] CPU: Physical Processor ID: 0
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.937386] CPU: Processor Core ID: 0
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10201.937386] CPU1: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.032158] CPU1: Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N270   @ 1.60GHz stepping 02
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.032331] CPU0 attaching NULL sched-domain.
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.060036] CPU0 attaching sched-domain:
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.060045]  domain 0: span 0-1 level SIBLING
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.060052]   groups: 0 (cpu_power = 589) 1 (cpu_power = 589)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.060067]   domain 1: span 0-1 level MC
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.060073]    groups: 0-1 (cpu_power = 1178)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.060085] CPU1 attaching sched-domain:
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.060091]  domain 0: span 0-1 level SIBLING
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.060097]   groups: 1 (cpu_power = 589) 0 (cpu_power = 589)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.060110]   domain 1: span 0-1 level MC
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.060116]    groups: 0-1 (cpu_power = 1178)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.064041] CPU1 is up
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.064231] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136298] i915 0000:00:02.0: restoring config space at offset 0xf (was 0x100, writing 0x10b)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136349] pci 0000:00:02.1: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x900000, writing 0x900007)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136410] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: restoring config space at offset 0x3 (was 0x0, writing 0x10)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136425] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x100006, writing 0x100002)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136475] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: restoring config space at offset 0xf (was 0x40100, writing 0x40103)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136497] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: restoring config space at offset 0x9 (was 0x10001, writing 0xf001f001)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136510] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: restoring config space at offset 0x8 (was 0x0, writing 0xf020f020)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136522] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: restoring config space at offset 0x7 (was 0x20000000, writing 0x2020)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136534] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: restoring config space at offset 0x6 (was 0x0, writing 0x20200)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136550] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: restoring config space at offset 0x3 (was 0x810000, writing 0x810010)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136565] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x100000, writing 0x100407)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136637] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: restoring config space at offset 0xf (was 0x40200, writing 0x4020b)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136659] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: restoring config space at offset 0x9 (was 0x10001, writing 0xf011f011)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136671] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: restoring config space at offset 0x8 (was 0x0, writing 0xf030f030)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136684] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: restoring config space at offset 0x7 (was 0x20000000, writing 0x3030)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136702] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: restoring config space at offset 0x3 (was 0x810000, writing 0x810010)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136716] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x100000, writing 0x100407)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136787] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: restoring config space at offset 0xf (was 0x40300, writing 0x40303)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136808] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: restoring config space at offset 0x9 (was 0x10001, writing 0x60116001)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136821] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: restoring config space at offset 0x8 (was 0x0, writing 0xf040f040)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136833] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: restoring config space at offset 0x7 (was 0x20000000, writing 0x4040)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136851] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: restoring config space at offset 0x3 (was 0x810000, writing 0x810010)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136865] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x100000, writing 0x100407)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.136950] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x2800005, writing 0x2800001)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.137003] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x2800005, writing 0x2800001)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.137055] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x2800005, writing 0x2800001)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.137107] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x2800005, writing 0x2800001)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.137169] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x2900006, writing 0x2900002)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.137221] pci 0000:00:1e.0: restoring config space at offset 0x9 (was 0x10001, writing 0x1fff1)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.137233] pci 0000:00:1e.0: restoring config space at offset 0x8 (was 0x0, writing 0xfff0)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.137246] pci 0000:00:1e.0: restoring config space at offset 0x7 (was 0x22800000, writing 0x228000f0)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.137341] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.1: restoring config space at offset 0xf (was 0x200, writing 0x2ff)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.137396] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: restoring config space at offset 0xf (was 0x200, writing 0x20a)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.137602] tg3 0000:02:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0xf (was 0x1f7, writing 0x10b)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.137631] tg3 0000:02:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0xc (was 0x0, writing 0x40000)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.137679] tg3 0000:02:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0x5 (was 0xfffffff7, writing 0x0)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.137698] tg3 0000:02:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0x4 (was 0xffff0004, writing 0xf0200004)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.137717] tg3 0000:02:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0x3 (was 0x0, writing 0x10)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.137741] tg3 0000:02:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x100000, writing 0x100006)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.138088] wl 0000:05:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0xf (was 0x100, writing 0x103)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.138158] wl 0000:05:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0x4 (was 0x4, writing 0xf0400004)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.138176] wl 0000:05:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0x3 (was 0x0, writing 0x10)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.138200] wl 0000:05:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x100000, writing 0x100006)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.138751] PM: early resume of devices complete after 2.603 msecs
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.544586] PM: resume of drv:battery dev:PNP0C0A:00 complete after 356.226 msecs
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.744266] PM: resume of drv:button dev:PNP0C0D:00 complete after 199.660 msecs
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.787064] i915 0000:00:02.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.787073] i915 0000:00:02.0: setting latency timer to 64
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.880374] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 22 (level, low) -> IRQ 22
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.880405] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.880475] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 23 (level, low) -> IRQ 23
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.880486] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: setting latency timer to 64
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.880517] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.880548] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: PCI INT B -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.880558] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: setting latency timer to 64
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.880587] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.880616] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: PCI INT C -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 18
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.880626] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: setting latency timer to 64
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.880655] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.880684] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: PCI INT D -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.880694] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: setting latency timer to 64
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.880723] usb usb5: root hub lost power or was reset
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.880752] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: PCI INT A -> GSI 23 (level, low) -> IRQ 23
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.880763] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: setting latency timer to 64
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.880808] pci 0000:00:1e.0: setting latency timer to 64
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.880832] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.1: PCI INT B -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.880841] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.1: setting latency timer to 64
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.882355] ata2: port disabled. ignoring.
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.882388] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: PCI INT B -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.882397] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: setting latency timer to 64
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.882745] wl 0000:05:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 18
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10202.882761] wl 0000:05:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10203.012175] PM: resume of drv:usb dev:usb1 complete after 128.696 msecs
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10203.164221] PM: resume of drv:usb dev:usb2 complete after 152.002 msecs
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10203.308221] PM: resume of drv:usb dev:usb3 complete after 143.958 msecs
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10203.388959] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10203.452223] PM: resume of drv:usb dev:usb4 complete after 143.959 msecs
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10203.596222] PM: resume of drv:usb dev:usb5 complete after 143.956 msecs
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10203.716199] usb 1-3: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10203.892494] PM: resume of drv:usb dev:1-3 complete after 287.337 msecs
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10204.004222] usb 1-5: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10204.144099] PM: resume of drv:usb dev:1-5 complete after 251.567 msecs
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10204.144127] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10207.920183] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10215.524184] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.172621] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/03:0c:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.172630] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/03:42:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.180509] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/33
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.181473] PM: resume of drv:sd dev:0:0:0:0 complete after 15037.336 msecs
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.181510] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.331328] PM: resume of drv:sd dev:2:0:0:0 complete after 149.809 msecs
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.378843] PM: resume of devices complete after 17239.622 msecs
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379178] PM: resume devices took 17.240 seconds
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379182] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379198] WARNING: at /build/buildd/linux-2.6.32/kernel/power/suspend_test.c:53 suspend_test_finish+0x89/0x90()
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379203] Hardware name: 406822U         
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379207] Component: resume devices, time: 17240
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379211] Modules linked in: ppp_deflate zlib_deflate bsd_comp ppp_async crc_ccitt nls_utf8 isofs option usbserial binfmt_misc ppdev snd_hda_codec_realtek joydev fbcon tileblit font bitblit softcursor vga16fb vgastate snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm_oss snd_mixer_oss snd_pcm snd_seq_dummy snd_seq_oss snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi snd_seq_midi_event snd_seq snd_timer lib80211_crypt_tkip snd_seq_device i915 drm_kms_helper uvcvideo wl(P) snd drm psmouse intel_agp videodev v4l1_compat serio_raw lib80211 soundcore i2c_algo_bit snd_page_alloc agpgart coretemp video output lp parport usb_storage tg3
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379293] Pid: 4048, comm: pm-suspend Tainted: P           2.6.32-25-generic #44-Ubuntu
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379298] Call Trace:
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379309]  [<c014c6e2>] warn_slowpath_common+0x72/0xa0
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379318]  [<c0183e89>] ? suspend_test_finish+0x89/0x90
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379325]  [<c0183e89>] ? suspend_test_finish+0x89/0x90
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379332]  [<c014c75b>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x2b/0x30
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379340]  [<c0183e89>] suspend_test_finish+0x89/0x90
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379348]  [<c0183c61>] suspend_devices_and_enter+0xa1/0xd0
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379356]  [<c058abad>] ? printk+0x1d/0x20
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379362]  [<c0183d4d>] enter_state+0xbd/0xf0
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379370]  [<c0183405>] state_store+0x75/0xc0
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379377]  [<c0183390>] ? state_store+0x0/0xc0
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379385]  [<c034cf60>] kobj_attr_store+0x20/0x30
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379394]  [<c025e8e5>] sysfs_write_file+0x95/0x100
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379402]  [<c0208942>] vfs_write+0xa2/0x1a0
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379409]  [<c025e850>] ? sysfs_write_file+0x0/0x100
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379417]  [<c058f780>] ? do_page_fault+0x160/0x3a0
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379425]  [<c0209262>] sys_write+0x42/0x70
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379432]  [<c01033ec>] syscall_call+0x7/0xb
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379440]  [<c0590000>] ? show_kprobe_addr+0x30/0x100
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379445] ---[ end trace b35b243f5444312d ]---
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379541] PM: Finishing wakeup.
Oct 12 16:33:33 unteer kernel: [10219.379544] Restarting tasks ... done.
```

Comment: What do the system logs (especially the kernel log `/var/log/kern.log`) show around the time of the standbys?

Comment: I added a relevant kern.log extract.  Nothing caught my eye when looking, but I have no experience in diagnosing a problem like this :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do in this case is make sure that I can SSH into the netbook from another computer. With the netbook close by and visible, on the secondary computer run the `top` command and closely monitor the output so that when the netbook goes into standby you will see what command/app is executed. From there you can further troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I see the value in that, but the problem is that it's sporadic, so I would theoretically need to be monitoring the netbook at all times.  In this situation, that's not a viable solution, but I appreciate the angle.

Comment: @Jonathan - You could always send the output to a file so you don't have to sit around waiting.